# Not getting current user id in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am trying to do verification using firebase by phone number I want to get the current user id in my verification activity to store user id in database.

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
String code;
String mobile;
String codesent;
//  public FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify_phone);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String uId = mAuth.getUid();


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), uId,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    sendVerificationCode();


    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            verifySignInCode();


        }
    });

}
```

Comment: _Not getting current user id_ : What do you have instead ? Do you have an error ?

Comment: its not toasting

Comment: Is there any stacktrace ? Have you tried using a debugger ?

Comment: i did not tried

Comment: Have you tried now ?